# The double cone is not locally euclidean

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, algebraic-topology

Let $\mathcal{C}=\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^3 | x^2+y^2=z^2\}$. Prove that $\mathcal{C}$ is not locallly euclidean.

I consider $\mathbf{x}=(0,0,0)$ and $U$ an open neighbourood of $\mathbf{x}$ in $\mathcal{C}$. I suppose that exists $\varphi:U\to D^n$ homeomorfism. So, it's true that $U\setminus \{\mathbf{x}\}\cong_{hom} D^n\setminus \{\varphi(\mathbf{x})\}$. However, this can be possible only if $n=1$. In fact, $U\smallsetminus \{\mathbf{x}\}$ has got at least two connected components while $D^n\setminus \{\varphi(\mathbf{x})\}$ has got

$0$ connected comp. if $n=0$ (is the empty)

$1$ connected comp. if $n\geq 2$  (is connected)

$2$ connected comp. if $n=1$ (is a segment without a point)

So, let $n=1$. Let $\varphi:U\to D^1$ homeomorfism. I consider $U'=\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^3 | |z|<\varepsilon\}$ con $\varepsilon>0$ such that $U'\subseteq U$. So, $U'$ is open and connected. So, I have that $\varphi(U')$ is open and connected because $\varphi$ is homeomorfism. \ Moreover, the restriction $\varphi_{|U'}:U'\to \varphi(U')$ is still an homeomorfism and $\varphi(U')\cong_{hom} D^1$. On the other hand, $\forall \mathbf{y}\ne (0,0,0)$, $U'\setminus  \{\mathbf{y}\}$ is connected while $\varphi(U')\setminus \{\varphi(\mathbf{y})\}$ has got two connected components. This cannot be possible because $\varphi$ is homeomorfism, so, $U\not\cong_{hom} D^1$. Follows that $\mathcal{C}$ is not locally $n$-euclidean for any $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and so $\mathcal{C}$ is not locally euclidean.

Is this proof correct? I followed my teacher's suggestions but I'm not sure if it's all well written. In particular, the conclusion is correct?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm confused. $n$ can only equal $2$ (by considering $C$ away from the origin).

Comment: I'm trying to prove that C is not locally euclidean in the origin

Comment: Yes, but the dimension (of a manifold) is globally constant on a connected space. This follows from invariance of domain (or from linear algebra in the smooth case). It’s hard for us to know exactly what your course/exercise has established.

Comment: This exercise is given to me as an example of a non locally euclidean topological space, immediately after the definition of a locally euclidean topological space. Then, my teacher gives me the theorem of invariance of domain by Brouwer

Comment: Ah, OK, so then I guess your approach makes good sense.

Comment: I think his goal is to show that the double cone is not locally $n$-Euclidean for any $n$. It excludes all $n\ne 1$ due to the number of connected components and then studies in detail the case $n=1$ which is the only one that remains possible. I don't quite understand how he comes to conclude that homeomorphism cannot exist in this case. If it helps, my def of locally $n$-euclidean topological space is the following: X is locally $n$-euclidean iff $\forall x\in X$ exists an open neighbourhood of $x$ that is homeomorfic to the $n$-dimensional ball.

Comment: The argument is correct, but it seems you yourself don't quite understand it, so it would probably be best if you elaborated on which part you are skeptical of. BTW, the notation $D^n$ is typically for the closed $n$-disk, but you should rather be working with the open $n$-disk $B^n$.

Comment: Yes, you're right but my teacher denotes with $D^n$ the open ball. By the way, my fault is on the contraddiction found taken $\mathbf{y}\ne (0,0,0)$.